# prevent insert empty string to database

Tags: php, mysql, forms, session

i have this insert statement and i wold like to prevent the insert of rows where the item value is empty

```html
<?php
require_once 'app/helpers.php';
session_start();
$error = '';
$link = mysqli_connect(MYSQL_HOST, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PWD, MYSQL_DB);
mysqli_set_charset($link,"utf8");

$id = $_SESSION['user_id'] ;

$type = $_SESSION['user_rule'];

if($_POST) {

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $tel = $_POST['tel'];
    $prod = $_POST['prod'];
    $for = $_POST['for'];
    $s_date = $_POST['s_date'];
    $s_time = $_POST['s_time'];
    $e_date = $_POST['e_date'];
    $e_time = $_POST['e_time'];

    $item1 = $_POST['itm1'];
    $item2 = $_POST['itm2'];
    $item3 = $_POST['itm3'];
    $item4 = $_POST['itm4'];
    $item5 = $_POST['itm5'];
    $item6 = $_POST['itm6'];
    $item7 = $_POST['itm7'];
    $item8 = $_POST['itm8'];
    $notes = $_POST['notes'];

    if (empty($prod)) {
        $error = '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button> מי מפיק את כל הכיף הזה? בבקשה לרשום  </div>';

    } elseif (empty($for)) {
        $error = '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button> כן? למי הציוד הולך בבקשה? </div>';
    } elseif (empty($s_date)) {
        $error = '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button> מתי מתחיל כל הכיף הזה?  </div>';
    } elseif (empty($s_time)) {
        $error = '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>  באיזה שעה מתחיל הכיף?</div>';
    } elseif (empty($e_date)) {
        $error = '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>  מתי נגמר הכאב ראש הזה?</div>';
    } elseif (empty($e_time)) {
        $error = '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button> באיזה שעה נגמר הכאב ראש? שנדע לקחת כדור </div>';
    } else {
        if (!empty($item1)) {
            $rent = "INSERT INTO rent (u_name,u_id,mail,phone,prod,rent_for,start_d,start_t,end_d,end_t,item,user_type,notes)
VALUES 
('$name','$id','$email','$tel','$prod','$for','$s_date','$s_time','$e_date','$e_time','$item1','$type','$notes')  ";
            mysqli_query($link, $rent);
            $error = '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button> הזמנתך בוצעה - עכשיו חכה בסבלנות אל תאכל את הראש </div>';

        }
        if (!empty($item2)){
            $rent = "INSERT INTO rent (u_name,u_id,mail,phone,prod,rent_for,start_d,start_t,end_d,end_t,item,user_type,notes)
VALUES 
('$name','$id','$email','$tel','$prod','$for','$s_date','$s_time','$e_date','$e_time','$item2','$type','$notes')  ";
            mysqli_query($link, $rent);
            $error = '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button> הזמנתך בוצעה - עכשיו חכה בסבלנות אל תאכל את הראש </div>';
        }

        if (!empty($item3)){
            $rent = "INSERT INTO rent (u_name,u_id,mail,phone,prod,rent_for,start_d,start_t,end_d,end_t,item,user_type,notes)
VALUES 
('$name','$id','$email','$tel','$prod','$for','$s_date','$s_time','$e_date','$e_time','$item3','$type','$notes')  ";
            mysqli_query($link, $rent);
            $error = '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button> הזמנתך בוצעה - עכשיו חכה בסבלנות אל תאכל את הראש </div>';
        }
        if (!empty($item4)){
            $rent = "INSERT INTO rent (u_name,u_id,mail,phone,prod,rent_for,start_d,start_t,end_d,end_t,item,user_type,notes)
VALUES 
('$name','$id','$email','$tel','$prod','$for','$s_date','$s_time','$e_date','$e_time','$item4','$type','$notes')  ";
            mysqli_query($link, $rent);
            $error = '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button> הזמנתך בוצעה - עכשיו חכה בסבלנות אל תאכל את הראש </div>';
        }
        if (!empty($item4)){
            $rent = "INSERT INTO rent (u_name,u_id,mail,phone,prod,rent_for,start_d,start_t,end_d,end_t,item,user_type,notes)
VALUES 
('$name','$id','$email','$tel','$prod','$for','$s_date','$s_time','$e_date','$e_time','$item4','$type','$notes')  ";
            mysqli_query($link, $rent);
            $error = '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button> הזמנתך בוצעה - עכשיו חכה בסבלנות אל תאכל את הראש </div>';
        }
        if (!empty($item5)){
            $rent = "INSERT INTO rent (u_name,u_id,mail,phone,prod,rent_for,start_d,start_t,end_d,end_t,item,user_type,notes)
VALUES 
('$name','$id','$email','$tel','$prod','$for','$s_date','$s_time','$e_date','$e_time','$item5','$type','$notes')  ";
            mysqli_query($link, $rent);
            $error = '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button> הזמנתך בוצעה - עכשיו חכה בסבלנות אל תאכל את הראש </div>';
        }
        if (!empty($item6)){
            $rent = "INSERT INTO rent (u_name,u_id,mail,phone,prod,rent_for,start_d,start_t,end_d,end_t,item,user_type,notes)
VALUES 
('$name','$id','$email','$tel','$prod','$for','$s_date','$s_time','$e_date','$e_time','$item6','$type','$notes')  ";
            mysqli_query($link, $rent);
            $error = '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button> הזמנתך בוצעה - עכשיו חכה בסבלנות אל תאכל את הראש </div>';
        }
        if (!empty($item7)){
            $rent = "INSERT INTO rent (u_name,u_id,mail,phone,prod,rent_for,start_d,start_t,end_d,end_t,item,user_type,notes)
VALUES 
('$name','$id','$email','$tel','$prod','$for','$s_date','$s_time','$e_date','$e_time','$item7','$type','$notes')  ";
            mysqli_query($link, $rent);
            $error = '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button> הזמנתך בוצעה - עכשיו חכה בסבלנות אל תאכל את הראש </div>';
        }
        if (!empty($item8)){
            $rent = "INSERT INTO rent (u_name,u_id,mail,phone,prod,rent_for,start_d,start_t,end_d,end_t,item,user_type,notes)
VALUES 
('$name','$id','$email','$tel','$prod','$for','$s_date','$s_time','$e_date','$e_time','$item8','$type','$notes')  ";
            mysqli_query($link, $rent);
            $error = '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button> הזמנתך בוצעה - עכשיו חכה בסבלנות אל תאכל את הראש </div>';
        }

    }

}
?>

<?= $error ?>
```

how can i prevent of insert each row where the item1 or item2 or item3  value is empty? and insert only the rows where the item value is no empty ?

the result i get now is 8 rows in my database table with empty cell in the item column

Comment: Side note: You are leaving yourself open to an SQL injection; use a prepared statement.

Comment: this is for test interment only just for practices code

Comment: `if($_POST){` You start off as that but trying to check for `empty()` after that. I'd start by getting rid of `if($_POST){` and check for empty fields first, then query and not allow for empty/NULL values in your db or vice-versa.

Comment: You shouldn't practice with bad code.  Practice using prepared statements

Comment: Don't practice with bad habits. Habits tend to follow you later on and might bite you in the "you know what" ;-)

Comment: You could also use a ternary operator.

Comment: @drorshalit I don't know about you, but I don't usually practice things by doing them the incorrect/insecure way. Shouldn't you practice to write the best code possible? Do you "practice" cooking macaroni and cheese by starting to boil it and then stirring it with your bare hands?

Comment: Your code isn't testing for empty of the item fields.  You're testing the other fields, but not the items.  Test each one, and if not empty, run a single insert.  Not elegant, but consistent at least ..

Comment: There should be a simpler way to achieve what you are trying to do. Those insert statements can easily be reduced by using a loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I imagine you needs insert 8 items, like a details right?

You can create a function to do the insert in the database, so on that case you will be able to call that funcion every time when the item isn't empty.

Something like so...

```
<?php
require_once 'app/helpers.php';
session_start();
$error = '';

$link = mysqli_connect(MYSQL_HOST, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PWD, MYSQL_DB);
mysqli_set_charset($link,"utf8");

$id = $_SESSION['user_id'] ;

$type = $_SESSION['user_rule'];

if($_POST){

    $item1 = $_POST['itm1'];
    $item2 = $_POST['itm2'];
    $item3 = $_POST['itm3'];
    $item4 = $_POST['itm4'];
    $item5 = $_POST['itm5'];
    $item6 = $_POST['itm6'];
    $item7 = $_POST['itm7'];
    $item8 = $_POST['itm8'];

if(empty($prod)){
    $error = '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button> מי מפיק את כל הכיף הזה? בבקשה לרשום  </div>';

}elseif (empty($for)){
    $error = '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button> כן? למי הציוד הולך בבקשה? </div>';
}elseif (empty($s_date)){
    $error = '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button> מתי מתחיל כל הכיף הזה?  </div>';
}elseif (empty($s_time)){
    $error = '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>  באיזה שעה מתחיל הכיף?</div>';
}elseif(empty($e_date)){
    $error = '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>  מתי נגמר הכאב ראש הזה?</div>';
}elseif (empty($e_time)){
    $error = '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button> באיזה שעה נגמר הכאב ראש? שנדע לקחת כדור </div>';
}else{

    insertItem($item1, $_POST);
    insertItem($item2, $_POST);
    insertItem($item3, $_POST);
    insertItem($item4, $_POST);
    insertItem($item5, $_POST);
    insertItem($item6, $_POST);
    insertItem($item7, $_POST);
    insertItem($item8, $_POST);

    $error = '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button> הזמנתך בוצעה - עכשיו חכה בסבלנות אל תאכל את הראש </div>';

}


}


?>

    <?= $error ?>

<?php

function insertItem($item, $post) {
    // this should prevent to insert an empty item in the database
    if (!empty($item)) {
        $name = $post['name'];
        $email = $post['email'];
        $tel = $post['tel'];
        $prod = $post['prod'];
        $for = $post['for'];
        $s_date = $post['s_date'];
        $s_time = $post['s_time'];
        $e_date = $post['e_date'];
        $e_time = $post['e_time'];
        $notes = $_POST['notes'];

        $rent = "
        INSERT INTO rent (u_name,u_id,mail,phone,prod,rent_for,start_d,start_t,end_d,end_t,item,user_type,notes)
            VALUES 
        ('$name','$id','$email','$tel','$prod','$for','$s_date','$s_time','$e_date','$e_time','$item','$type','$notes')";
        mysqli_query($link,$rent);
    }
}
```

BTW: I think you can organize better your code like MVC or so, well, let me know if this works for you

regards!

Answer (score -4):

Try something like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['name']) && $_POST['name']!=""){
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Is that not the same as if(!empty($_POST['name']))?

Comment: @markmoxx I would argue that `!empty()` is better actually, especially from a readability standpoint

Comment: The syntax isn't the issue here; this answer doesn't address the actual question

Comment: if i use the if(!empty) and the first item will be not empty so it will stop there and not move on to the next statement

Comment: i have updated the post. any better way to do this? and yes i know that i am open for SQL injection i will fix my coding practices :)